# URLrewritefilter(Tucky) error

Tags: servlets, url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I'm trying to rewrite url using tucky. Here is my rule.

```
<rule>
    <from>^/dev/([_A-Za-z0-9.@-]*)/([a-z.-]*)$</from>
    <to>webl?handler=developers&amp;userid=$1&amp;action=$2</to>
</rule>
```

Error details:

```
Context Path:/OPMS
Servlet Path:/dev/benjamin/webl
Path Info:null
Query String:handler=developers&userid=benjamin&action=webl
```

I'm clicking on this link from a page at `/OPMS/webl`. Why is `$2` become "webl"? It is the name of my servlet. And also why they have servlet path: `/dev/benjamin/webl`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was not having a context path.

```
<to context="WebAppName">/webl?handler=developers&amp;userid=$1&amp;action=$2</to>
```